# Configure base url in Zero to JupyterHub with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, kubernetes-helm, jupyterhub

I want to change the base url of my JupyterHub, how can I do this with the [Zero to Jupyterhub with Kubernetes project](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#)?

I know it is possible to change the hub's base url, it is stated on the bottom of this page: https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started/networking-basics.html. But I can't find it as config parameter in the [Configuration Reference](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can put in config.yaml of helm:

```
hub:
  baseUrl: /jupyter
```